# docker stack mysql service start then stop again

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have an issue with mysql service it started then stopped when i deploy the stack. I am not really sure what is wrong. There are no errors on the logs. It works fine on docker-compose I am not sure why it keep shutting down when i deploy it. From the error log i am getting this in line 191:    47 Killed "$@" --initialize-insecure --default-time-zone=SYSTEM
can this be the source of the problem? I am using this version of mysql [mysql official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

```html
services:
  db: 
    image: mysql
    #container_name: mysql_db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - mysql_root_password
      - mysql_database
      - mysql_user
      - mysql_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_database
      MYSQL_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_password
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
 
    networks:
      - back-tier

    volumes:
      - alpine-db_backup:/var/lib/mysql
      - alpine-mysql_logs:/var/log/mysql
      - alpine-mysql_cnf:/etc/mysql
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 60s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        max_failure_ratio: 0.3
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 90M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 50M
```

```html
networks:
    front-tier:
      driver: overlay
    back-tier:
      driver: overlay
```

Error Logs

```html
client_db.1.vvhd3rxc245e@worker-1    | 2021-12-02 04:45:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.1.vvhd3rxc245e@worker-1    | 2021-12-02 04:45:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
client_db.1.vvhd3rxc245e@worker-1    | 2021-12-02 04:45:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.2.88e3qb36ensi@worker-1    | 2021-12-02 04:44:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.2.88e3qb36ensi@worker-1    | 2021-12-02 04:44:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
client_db.2.88e3qb36ensi@worker-1    | 2021-12-02 04:44:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.1.x4976pxrrumi@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:43:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.1.x4976pxrrumi@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:43:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
client_db.1.x4976pxrrumi@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:43:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.3.my3k6agifuun@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:44:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.3.my3k6agifuun@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:44:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
client_db.3.my3k6agifuun@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:44:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.3.yu9cgxx0jn1b@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:43:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.3.yu9cgxx0jn1b@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:43:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
client_db.3.yu9cgxx0jn1b@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:43:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.2.y2pd68ny9yn5@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:44:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.2.y2pd68ny9yn5@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:44:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
client_db.2.y2pd68ny9yn5@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:44:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:33:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:33:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:33:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | 2021-12-02 04:33:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | 2021-12-02T04:33:40.858385Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | 2021-12-02T04:33:40.858893Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) initializing of server in progress as process 45
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | 2021-12-02T04:33:40.870822Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | 2021-12-02T04:33:44.274928Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
client_db.2.tx9luw14iylo@worker-2    | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 191:    45 Killed                  "$@" --initialize-insecure --default-time-zone=SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out i wasn't making the mysql service persistent in my stack application which was causing the mysql container to keep shutting down when i deploy the stack. So i made the mysql service persistent by setting the constraint to run on the Manager node because i had create the volume on the manager node and then map the node to the container so that the container can have persistent data. This solve the solve the issue.

```html
db: 
    image: mysql
    #container_name: mysql_db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - mysql_root_password
      - mysql_database
      - mysql_user
      - mysql_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_database
      MYSQL_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_password
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
 
    networks:
      - back-tier

    volumes:
      - alpine-db_backup:/var/lib/mysql
      - alpine-mysql_logs:/var/log/mysql
      - alpine-mysql_cnf:/etc/mysql
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      resources:
        reservations:
          memory: 128M
        limits:
          memory: 256M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 60s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        max_failure_ratio: 0.3
```